# How to remove additional numbers in each cell in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am doing some data analyzing with R. I read a csv file. I would like to eliminate `000,000,000` from each cell. How can I get rid of only 000? I tried to use `grep()`, but it dropped rows.

This is the dataframe:

[image: data]

Comment: Try `gsub('000','',df$VIOLATIONS_RAW)`

Comment: Please, when you ask a question, include data in your actual post - not a link (and definitely not a link to a screenshot).  Provide code that generates data and then demonstrates your problem, along with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have included dummy data based on your screenshot (and please attention to coment of @andrew_reece):

```
#Code
df$NewVar <- trimws(gsub('000','',df$VIOLATIONS_RAW),whitespace = ',')
```

Output:

```
   VIOLATIONS_RAW      NewVar
1 202,403,506,000 202,403,506
2     213,145,123 213,145,123
3         212,000         212
4 123,000,000,000         123
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(VIOLATIONS_RAW = c("202,403,506,000", "213,145,123", 
"212,000", "123,000,000,000")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do in a general way to remove any number of 0's

```
df$VIOLATIONS_RAW <- trimws(gsub("(?<=,)0+(?=(,|$))", "", 
    df$VIOLATIONS_RAW, perl = TRUE), whitespace=",")
df$VIOLATIONS_RAW
#[1] "202,403,506" "213,145,123" "212"         "123"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(VIOLATIONS_RAW = c("202,403,506,000", "213,145,123", 
"212,000", "123,000,000,000")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```